# How do I destroy the penguin mothership?

Tags: starbound

Also finally constructing the distress beacon and activating it, a gigantic penguin summoning UFO attacked and quickly killed me. When I returned to my world it was no longer there for me to try again.

So of course I gathered the distress beacon materials again and gave this another go (being more cautious this time). I hit the UFO a few times with my iron hunting bow to very, very little effect. The penguins also took quite a few shots to bring down. I attempted to melee the penguins to kill them faster and was once again killed almost instantaneously.

Before I waste a third distress beacon (finding those materials is a huge pain), what level of armor/weaponry should I have? I've done a bit of exploring on this planet and have found no structures with anything that might help me (save for one empty Apex outpost, still no help).

Comment: A friend of mine is having this early-game problem too.  The tutorial unfortunately encourages you to build a distress beacon before being properly equipped to fight such an onslaught.  I'd suggest ignoring it until you have much better weapons and armor.  Or possibly running when they come and are hostile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the patch that rebalanced armor, weapons, and enemy difficulty, this fight has become much easier. I completed it easily with one or two bandages, copper armor, an iron bow, and an iron melee weapon. The summoned penguins all died in one to two shots of my Hunting Knife. After that I just needed to keep firing arrows at the mothership and occasionally dodge its blast. Even if I got hit, bandages could easily keep up with the damage.

I'm pretty sure you don't even need to bother with copper armor to beat this in its current state. Unless you're absolutely terrible at combat, you probably need only the following to take out this boss:

- An iron weapon such as the Hunting Knife (10 iron bars, 30 pixels), to dispatch penguin enemies quickly.
- The iron bow (15 iron bars, 150 pixels, and your previous hunting bow) to shoot at the mothership. You could probably do it with the normal Hunting Bow too, but why make the fight more tedious on yourself?
- Bandages (4 plant fibre each). 10 should be plenty, but if you want to be sure, just stock up on a bunch.
- A basic shield (10 wood planks, 10 iron bars, 20 pixels) is by no means necessary, but binding it to the right mouse button can be handy so that you can block while bandaging yourself. You can use bandages *while* blocking, which means you can basically back yourself into a corner and become immune to damage (or at least take greatly reduced damage) while you heal.

Total resource cost to prepare for this fight (assuming you've already crafted everything along the quest line to get the ship to appear): 35 iron bars, 10 wood planks, 200 pixels, and 40+ plant fibres.

If you've got the copper handy and want to make yourself some copper armor, knock yourself out. I don't think you'll need it though. And if, like me, you had a ton of silver sitting around too, keep in mind that after this fight, you'll probably just be upgrading straight to silver armor anyway, since it unlocks soon after.

Comment: I haven't played the new update much but it sounds promising

Answer (score 3):

Copper Armor upgraded into -> Silver Armor  will reduce the fatal blow of the rocket penguins and tank shells to a mere 28 damage.

They're nerfing the leather winter armor (it's on par with Gold, which is next "Tier" after UFO) in next patch (tomorrow as of this post).

Your best bet is to get the Silver Armor and then go raiding Threat 10 planets to find an Armor Pen 10 weapon, or if you are lucky find a flat land with an anchor (if you have a way to go up high enough) to an Avian Airship and get a pair of guns. I solo'd the ufo with a pair of Tech level 10 pistols

Comment: I think I found an anchor like this once but when I get to the top there was no chests or anything. At least nothing I can remember so it probably wasn't very good if there was something.

Comment: @Katustrawfic If you found an airship then there might be a quartermaster you can purchase weapons off of (for pixels)

Comment: As of the latest patch, you can't craft silver armor until *after* this fight.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to destoy the mothership with the iron bow, try sitting near the base of a cave that go's down at about a 45 degree angle, And just shoot outwards, it takes a while but it works. Also try the snow infantry armor you get from the yarnspinning wheel, and have plenty of bandages and/or milk, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I recall in demo streaming, *three* guys spend much time trying kill it using *submachine guns*. And they were almost killed (they were incredibly dumb however), but anyway I guess that bow is far below from the required weapons level to kill mothership.

Comment: This seems unfair since I can't make any better weapons than what I already have. I may just restart on a new world and see what I can find there then.

Comment: @Katustrawfic the game is in early beta, it's quite possible something is not right. But can't you also travel to another planets using the ship (I personally had no time yet to try the game, but will soon)?

Comment: Since it was the next quest, it seemed like this boss fight shouldn't be as hard as it actually is. You can travel to other planets without fighting it, yes. But that wasn't at all obvious in-game.

Comment: @Katustrawfic well, maybe, but IMO difficulty and reasonable "non-obviousness" levels are eventually a good thing (easy & obvious -> boring).

Comment: With space travel being a key part to the game, it seems like at least that would be more obvious than it is.

Answer (score 0):

Well i know in the recent patch he lowered the penguin UFO level to make it level nine and I beat it on the first try earlier. I had full silver armor and used a bow and arrow and the dash tech to dodge it a lot and tried to lower it as low as possible to try and hit it with my watersword that I got from a miniboss earlier that does pretty mad damage. The tech was a huge help so if you're struggling a lot it might be worth going to look for some tech in one of the dungeons on another planet. After beating it i discovered it unlocks a whole new tier of items and a higher difficulty of the galaxy and steel armor and gun making stuff so I think you have to knuckle down and fight it with the bow and silver stuff. It is possible now though.

Comment: I did in fact find the energy dash tech already. And this new Snow Infantry armor actually has just a bit more defense so I guess I can give it a go now.

Comment: It took a while and 20+ bandages but I managed to beat the thing.

Comment: As of the latest patch, you can't craft silver armor until after this fight.

Answer (score 0):

Get a bunch of leather and make the snow infantry armor. Not only does it let you go to the ice planets but it has the highest armor up to this point. Way more than the metal armors.

Stay far away from your home when you trigger the fight because the boss can smash bricks loose.

I ended up running to a mine I had started to dig but abandoned I had lots of tunnels at the surface going to different directions.

The boss will still smash block loose but you can snipe it with your iron bow and hide while it shoots or smashes.

The penguins don't seem to be able to jump so dig some holes around the area where you build your fox hole. Once I got half of its life gone it got stuck in a block and it just stopped moving allowing me to shoot it easily.

It might be good to equip a shield they seem to block all damage and will probably block the ships blasts as well.

Comment: Snow infantry armor no longer gives the huge armor bonus it used to. It now gives slightly less protection than copper.

Answer (score 0):

I had silver armor and it only took a couple bombs to take down.. be careful when throwing them.. I was collateral on a couple throws :P

Comment: Huh, I didn't even think about bombs. With the character reset coming soon I'll have to give those a try.

Comment: Bomb have armor penetration 15, the will make massive damage to level 9 enemy

Comment: Can you elaborate on where to get bombs?

Answer (score -2):

So - Easy way is just to make a box around your self, make small holes in the top ( shift + click with pickaxe ) shoot him or hit him through the wall with a melee weapon, it's cheating, but this is an example boss pretty much, it's actually more late game then "first" boss material.

Comment: This was patched out. The boss smashed any blocks.